# What tools are needed to DIY wheel alignment?

Tags: tools, alignment

As per [this article](http://www.caranddriver.com/features/get-in-line-do-it-yourself-wheel-alignment), DIY-ing wheel alignment requires a [camber gauge](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VAS0WY) and either a [toe bar](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VAOHB2) or toe plates.  Is that a complete list of tools required?  Is it better to use a toe bar than toe plates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your link is actually for toe plates and not the bar. I think either work very well, but I am preferential to the plates like what you have shown. It comes with identical tape measures and for the price I don't think you can beat it. Same with the camber gauge ... it would fit the bill quite nicely. The only other thing you'd need are the hand tools to do the adjustments. That is going to vary by car, but the measurement tools are the big parts of the deal.